Eliminar elementos duplicados de un array en JavaScript de manera eficiente
Explicación del problema:
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en JavaScript donde necesito eliminar los elementos duplicados de un array de manera eficiente. Dada la matriz ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'], el resultado deseado es ['a', 'b', 'c'], donde cada elemento aparece solo una vez en el array resultante.
He intentado resolver este problema utilizando un bucle for y comparando cada elemento con los elementos anteriores, pero parece ser ineficiente. ¿Existe una forma más elegante y eficiente de lograr esto, quizás utilizando métodos integrados de JavaScript como filter o Set?


function eliminarDuplicados(array) {
    return Array.from(new Set(array));
}

let array = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'];
console.log(eliminarDuplicados(array));



Este código utiliza Set para eliminar duplicados y luego convierte el Set de vuelta a un array. Si bien funciona, estoy interesado en saber si hay otras alternativas más eficientes.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! defini eficiente.. mas rapido?? menos memoria??? menos letras de codigo?? esta pregunta es muy abierta asi como esta...

puedes leer este articulo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array

En ES6 no creo que haya una forma más eficiente de hacerlo que con el método que describes. Si aún así fuese necesario hacerlo más rápido, tendrás que echarle un ojo es al proceso que crea ese array, si es posible que de salida sea un tipo Set para que ya venga sin duplicados y te ahorras ese filtrado.

Más "elegante" lo dudo. Yo hice unas pruebas para ver si había una forma más rápida y no la encontré. Mi suposición es que Set al ser un elemento nativo, está implementado en un lenguaje y/o forma que es más eficiente que cualquier algoritmo que puedas construir en javascript
